# Iterate through list in python and get highest value for a given element

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file made like so:

```
business unit; employee id; name; tax code;
1; 50; JOE BLOGGS; 123456789
1; 51; JOE BLOGGS; 123456789
1; 52; JOE BLOGGS; 123456789
3; 53; JOE BLOGGS; 123456789
5; 54; JOE BLOGGS; 123456789
```

The tax code is unique while the business units and id may vary.
Since the employee I need is always the last one, it being his most recent and thus active working position, how can I loop through this file and append ONLY the last row to the array? (**Edit: the last line or better the highest id referring to that particular person, there might be other employees in the file**)

my code is:

```
for line in csv:
 l = [i.strip() for i in line.split(';')]
 if l[3] not in d:
  d.append(l[3])
  c.append(l[2])
  b.append(l[1])
  a.append(l[0])
```

this way I obtain as a result a list containing only the first record, how can I get the last one?
Thank you!

Comment: your code is not valid.  `d.append[l3]` raises a TypeError, did you mean `d.append(l3)` With round brackets?

Comment: this will get the last line: `last_line = csv.readlines()[-1]` although if you need the other lines at all then you will want to keep a reference to the `x = csv.readlines()` then get the last element of it with `x[-1]`

Comment: Are there other tax codes in the file? Do you want to get the latest line for every tax code?

Comment: The question is incomplete. Care to complete it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that of course there are other rows and thus tax codes in the file, so it does not help getting the last line but I have to get the last line of that particular tax code/employee

Comment: @MicheleZacco, but you said "loop through this file and append ONLY the last row to the array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you'd like to get the last record for each `tax code`. Try this,

```
d = dict() # key by `tax code`
for line in csv:
    l = [i.strip() for i in line.split(';')]

    d[l[3]] = l # update

lists = d.values()
```

If your file is grouped by `tax code`, use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby),

```
import csv
import operator
import itertools

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    header = next(f, None)
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(f, key=operator.itemgetter(3)):
        last_line = list(group)[-1]

        print(last_line)
        5; 54; JOE BLOGGS; 123456789
```

---

Previous answer: read the last line from a csv file.

**Way 1: Use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)**

`skipinitialspace=True` is used to get rid of whitespace following the delimiter `;`.

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    headers = next(f, None) # the header
    lists = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)]

    print(lists[-1])
    # Output
    ['5', '54', 'JOE BLOGGS', '123456789']
```

**Way 2: Use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)**

```
import csv
import collections

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    last_line = collections.deque(csv.reader(f), 1)[0][0]

    print(last_line)
    # Output
    5; 54; JOE BLOGGS; 123456789
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Grouping by tax code is ok; say I have other rows with other persons before and after my joe bloggs. How can I print out the last line (or highest id) for each different tax code?

Comment: @MicheleZacco, I believe that my first snippet code meets your requirements. Sort by `tax code` if necessary before `groupby`.

Comment: @MicheleZacco, I added a piece of code. Pls check it.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! This way I obtain the last line for each tax code. Is there a way to get the highest "id" per "tax code" instead? (in case say the person is moved to a "lower" business unit)